# Generating panel data in Stata

Tags: stata, panel-data

How can I generate panel data in Stata? 
I would like that each individual is affected by unobserved heterogeneity. 
For example, I want the DGP (data generating process) is something like:

Wages_{it}= \beta (Labor market experience_{it}) + \alpha_{i} + \epsilon_{it},

where \alpha_{i} is the unobserved heterogeneity and where \epsilon_{it} is the error term which is normally distributed.

Finally, I would like that (Labor market experience_{it}) is an AR(1) process, e.g.:

Labor market experience_{it}= 0.8 * (Labor market experience_{i,t-1}) + v_{it},

where v_{it} is the error term which is normally distributed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this by using subscripting combined with `bysort`:

```
clear
set seed 10011979
set obs 4 // Set the number of panels (N)
gen id = _n
gen alpha = rnormal(0,1)
expand 3 // Set the number of periods (T)
bys id: gen t=_n
xtset id t
bysort id (t): gen lme = rnormal(0,1) + rnormal(0,1) if _n==1
bysort id (t): replace lme = .8 * lme[_n-1] + rnormal(0,1) if _n!=1
gen w = 3 * lme + alpha + rnormal(0,1)
drop alpha
```